# I need to get cities related to property type using la lararvel,

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show all those city which is related to property type but unfortuntly i am getting all cities please help me how can i do that thanks.

property table has mf_city_id and property_type_id

please check property table https://ibb.co/R3qdq4z

**Property Model**

```
 public function propertyType()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PropertyType', 'id', 'property_type_id');
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = [
          
            'propertyCity' =>Property::with('propertyType')->get()->pluck('mf_city_id')- 
             >toArray(),

        ];
        return $data['propertyCity'];
        return view('home', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Property Model:

```
public function city(){
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'mf_city_id');
}
```

In PropertyType Model:

```
public function property(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'property_type_id');
}
```

In HomeController:

```
PropertyType::with("property.city");
```